# "Understanding a proof from the Mathematical Logic by H. Enderton"

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Im asked to rewrite and complete the following proof:

If #$\Gamma$ is recursiveand $Cn(\Gamma)$ is a complete theory, then #$Cn(\Gamma)$ is recursive.  Where #$ A$ is the set of Gödel numbers of all the sentences of the theory $A$ (set of sentences) and $Cn(A)$ is the set of consequences of $A$ ($Cn(A)=Th(Mod(A))$).

The proof states as follows: Analogue to other coloraly (25G: Let $A$ be a set of decidable sentences, and for any sentences $\sigma$, we have that $A \models \sigma$ or $A \not\models \sigma$ (thus by Completeness theorem, $A$ is a consistent theory), then $Cn(A)$ is decidable) and a set of sentences $A$ is decidable iff for each $\alpha$ exists an 'effective procedure' (probably by the ways of propositional calculus) that can decide whether $\alpha \in A$ or $\alpha \notin A$.

Now it states "Let (in the inconsistent case), consider $g(s)$ as: $g(s)$:= the least $d$ such that $s$ is not the Gödel number of a sentence or $d$ is in the set of item 18 and the last component of $d$ is either $s$ or $<h(() , h (\neg) > * s * < h ())>$ (i dont understand this notation). Thus $g$(#$\sigma)$ is $G$ (where $G$ is.. ) of the least deduction of $\sigma$ or $\neg \sigma$ from $A$. And $s$ $\in$ # $Cn(A)$ iff s>0 and the last component of $g(s)$ is $s$"

I appreciate any help to write this proof in the most successful way, thanks.

The book: A mathematical introduction to logic by Herbert Enderton

Comment: The last component of $d$ is either `s` or `(`$\lnot$`s)`.